# Arduino and RF communication

Tags: led, wireless, arduino-uno

I am currently working with arduino and rf module..I want to blink a led by arduino using rf module...I google it and the shown results required two arduino but I want to do this with only one arduino..Is there any way to do this..

Comment: What are you planning to use as a transmitter? I assume Arduino will be the receiver?

Comment: I want to use arduino as transmitter

Comment: I guess it now begs the question, what are you using for the receiver, (rf module p/n).  The standard arduino doesn't have an rf output, (though there may be a few similar versions that do).  The prior comment assumed the arduino on the receiver side since most simple rf modules require some type of logic control.

Comment: Unless you use an edit to just about entirely re-state this and make it clear, it will end up closed.  The obvious way to blink an LED with one Arduino would be to run the blink sketch, and not bother with RF module(s) at all.  If you do want to use a radio link, you'll need to be clear about what information is to be transmitted.  If that is digital information, you will likely either need a micontrontroller such as found on an Arduino at both the transmitter and receiver, or else these radios will need to be dedicated function units, either with fixed logic or built in microncontrollers.

Comment: It is unclear **what kind of RF module** you want to use, assuming a 315/433 MHz module then **no** you cannot use only one Arduino. The 315/433 MHz modules need a certain sequence of bits (a pattern) to be send so that the receiver can listen for that. **Creating** and transmitting and then receiving and **recognizing** that pattern requires **two** Arduinos. The transmitters/receivers are extremely simple and **each** need a microcontroller to do anything useful.

Comment: Well, you could connect two RF modules to a single Arduino board, though I struggle to see the point of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

A digital RF link would be great if it could reliably replace cable but it can't unless you take several measures to make the radio link robust enough. For instance, a simple receiver (in the absense of any transmitted signal) is likely to produce random data on its output because it is a dumb device. It will increase its RF gain to pick up on a weaker signal and, if a valid weaker signal isn't present, it will just amplify noise. At best, it might blank its output (based on the assumption that if the gain has to be so high then it is likely to be only noise).

If it blanks the output then maybe that would be a good starting point but if some random interference gets picked up that is higher than the blanking threshold, the output will toggle and turn the LED on or off.

So, what you get with a simple RF receiver connected to an LED with no relevant radio transmission is a randomly blinking LED. It might be off for periods of time but more than likely it will be flashing on and off because of the prevailing electromagnetic conditions on the receiver's antenna.

To overcome this, you use intelligence at the receiver's output to look for a data pattern that represents the transmission of a command to turn the LED on or off. This requires intelligence at the transmitter end and intelligence at the receiver end. This generally means MCUs at both ends.

Here is a picture I drew for another answer that gives an indication what can happen to the data output for an FM radio system: -

[image]

On the left there is no transmission and the red line trace is the output of the FM demodulator. It is producing seemingly random noise and the circuit that convertes this output to data (it's usually called a data slicer) is producing random ones and zeros (black trace). The blue trace is a signal created by the data slicer to use as a reference for deciding which digital state is represented by the red trace.

Then along comes a transmission and the FM demodulator output starts to make sense. The blue trace takes time to catch up and, after a short while it has locked into the transmitters preamble and is armed and ready for real data commands to be received.

Do you see the problem of making a robust (ish) radio link - you need intelligence at the receiver to make sense of things.

Comment: Ah the phantom downvoter strikes again!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to blink an LED with only one uC through a wireless link.  To do so, you can use two XBee radios in conjunction with an Arduino and utilize the XBee I/O Line Passing configuration.  You can find videos on YouTube as well as the Digi site that describe how to configure the radios for this feature.

This will allow you to connect the Arduino and LED as show in the schematic, run the blink sketch and the LED will blink as if it were connected directly to the Arduino.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXhlXV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Be well aware that the XBee is NOT 5v tolerant and you will need to implement some level shifting between it and the Arduino.  This may not be the cheapest way to do it, but should do what you want.

[Digi.com](https://www.digi.com/blog/videos/xbee-tech-tip-digital-io-line-passing-with-xbee/)

[YouTube Explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CLQEo2Ow1Qs)